# Pig UDF that produces output with the same schema as its input

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to create a UDF that accepts tuples and returns tuples.

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray);
DESCRIBE A
A: {f1: chararray}
B = FOREACH A GENERATE MyUDF(*);
DESCRIBE B
B: {(f1: chararray)}
```

However, I would like B to be of the form `{f1: chararray}`, i.e. I do not want a bag containing tuples of tuples containg a chararray but a bag of tuples containing a chararray.

I could use `FLATTEN` but then the schema looks as follows:
`B: {null::f1: chararray}` but I need it do be `{f1: chararray}`

Here is the code of my UDF:

```
public class MyTest extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    public MyTest() {
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(final Tuple input) throws IOException {
        //apply some logic (not relevant)
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(final Schema input) {
        try {
            final Schema outputTupleSchema = input.clone();
            return outputTupleSchema;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other ways to get around this, but the simplest is the one you are already using: `FLATTEN`.  Why not just assign the name you actually want?  You're going to have to `FLATTEN` regardless, because your UDF returns a tuple, and there's no way around that.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(MyUDF(*)) AS f1;
```

If you want to do this with a lot of fields, that might get cumbersome, but there could still be ways to minimize typing. (For example, wait until you've executed this UDF to provide your schema, instead of doing that at the `LOAD` statement).

Comment: the problem is that i need the schema in the udf so i'll have to specify it both on load and in the foreach. thanks anyway!

Comment: consider i have 500 coulmns, and i dont want `schema::f1` but  just `f1`, then in that case what should be done ? `return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema("schema", tupleSchema));`.
This is my return statement from `output schema()`.